De-Embedding Structures
I am trying to de-embed the attached ports and gnd plane to measure characteristic impedance of transmission lines in between the two port/small TLs.
I have tried techniques on

https://www.doe.carleton.ca/~nagui/labequip/loadpull/papers/sparams/Agilent_AN1364_S-parameter_De-embedding.pdf  and

https://scikit-rf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Deembedding.html (Fear that I am not defining Open and Short correctly)


But no successful results. I'll appreciate any suggestions.

